# noncommutative algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, banach-algebras

If we let $B$ be a noncommutative Banach algebra with unit $e$, then, obviously, $xy\not=yx$, but are they related? I suspect that the spectral radii of $xy$ and $yx$ are the same, but I couldn't prove it.

Comment: $\sigma(xy) \setminus \{0\} = \sigma(yx) \setminus \{0\}$ answers your question.

Comment: @Epsilon Ah, of course! thx.